# Google Analytics Repoting API .NET -

Tags: analytics, google-api-dotnet-client

Hello I am try to use Google Analytics API Ver 3 in ASP.NET/C# using a Service Account and can't seem to get it to work. Everything compiles but when calling  GaData d = r.Execute();
I get a GoogleApiException "Parameter validation failed for "ids". Any info/help on what could possibly cause this would be much appreciated.

```
        //This is the API url which we're storing to a string
        string scope = AnalyticsService.Scopes.AnalyticsReadonly.GetStringValue();

        //For whatever reason, this is labelled wrong. It is the email address
        //that you have added as a user to your Analytics account
        string clientId = "***********@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

        //This is the physical path to the key  file file.
        string keyFile = @"C:\key\***********.p12";

        //The password Google gives you.
        string keyPassword = "notasecret";

        //Store the authentication description
        AuthorizationServerDescription desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;

        //Create a certificate object to use when authenticating
        X509Certificate2 key = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, keyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        //Now, we will log in and authenticate, passing in the description
        //and key from above, then setting the accountId and scope
        AssertionFlowClient client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key)
        {
            ServiceAccountId = clientId,
            Scope = scope
        };

        //Finally, complete the authentication process
        //NOTE: This is the first change from the update above
        OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> auth =
            new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

        //First, create a new service object
        AnalyticsService gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { Authenticator = auth });

        //Create our query
        //The Data.Ga.Get needs the parameters:
        //Analytics account id, starting with ga:
        //Start date in format YYYY-MM-DD
        //End date in format YYYY-MM-DD
        //A string specifying the metrics
        DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest r =
            gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:nnnnnnnn", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-31", "ga:visitors");

        //Specify some addition query parameters
        r.Dimensions = "ga:pagePath";
        r.Sort = "-ga:visitors";
        r.MaxResults = 5;

        //Execute and fetch the results of our query
        GaData d = r.Execute();
```

---

1.Full Stack Trace

at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
   at Google.Apis.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient(CreateHttpClientArgs args) in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Release\release140\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Http\HttpClientFactory.cs:line 36
   at Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.CreateHttpClient(Initializer initializer) in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Release\release140\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Services\BaseClientService.cs:line 220
   at Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService..ctor(Initializer initializer) in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Release\release140\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Services\BaseClientService.cs:line 182
   at Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.AnalyticsService..ctor(Initializer initializer)
   at GoogleAnalyticDotNet.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\GoogleAnalyticDotNet\GoogleAnalyticDotNet\GoogleAnalyticDotNet\Program.cs:line 58
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: 1. Can you please add the full stack trace? It will be much easier to explore that one. 2. Did other calls worked for you? I want to figure out if it's only that service request which fails...

Comment: Hi peleyal, 1. I edited the post and added to stack trace. 2. No I haven't gotten any calls to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I complety derped out and left nnnnnnnn from the sample code...derp derp. Replace nnnnnn by the profile ID.. -.-

DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest r =
            gas.Data.Ga.Get("ga:nnnnnnnn", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-31", "ga:visitors");

Thanks peleyal for you're help.